# How to load the content from another file clicking on a link?

Tags: jquery, html

I have this code to load the content from another file

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("button").click(function(){
    $("#divA").load("book.html #divB");
  });
});
</script>

<button>Get</button>
```

This works, but I need the same thing with click on a link, instead of button

```
<a href="book.html">Get</a>
```

As per the user comment

I have another links on page. Only specific link should load the content.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply use `a` instead of `button`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#divA").load("book.html #divB");
  });
});
```

For specific `a` try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a#pass_your_id_here").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#divA").load("book.html #divB");
  });
});
```

Comment: Mr. Alien, I have another links on page. Only specific link should load the content.

Comment: @Alegro pass an ID or a class to `a`

Comment: @Alegro for example `$('a#pass_id_here')`

Comment: You also need to stop the link from being followed

Comment: @mplungjan was not aware he wanted a specific `a`

Comment: You STILL need to return false or prevent default

Answer (score 4):

Use the **anchor tag** as selector and make sure you stop the **default** action.

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
  $("a#id").on('click',function(){  // $("a#id")  or $("a.class") to target 
                                    //  specific anchors
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#divA").load("book.html #divB");
  });
});
```

Comment: So far the best answer! You were the first to stop the click

Answer (score 3):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#divA").load("book.html #divB");
  });
});
```

Comment: You also need to stop the link from being followed

Comment: Excuse me, all solutions work. Because I can accept only one, let's be the first answered. I voted for all another.

Comment: The best and first to cancel the link itself was [sushanth's](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13133678/295783)

Answer (score 3):

I think you want to load content of the url which is in anchor href

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#divA").load($(this).attr("href")+" #divB");
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is difficult you could have done it easily

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a").click(function(){
    $("#divA").load("book.html #divB");
  });
});
```

You can also assign `id` to your `a` tag and then do this

```
<a id="mylink" href="book.html">Get</a>

$(document).ready(function(){
       $("#mylink").click(function(){
       $("#divA").load("book.html #divB");
     });
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

if you have other links on page then you have to capture the div which holds the links:

```
$("#divlinkholder a").click(function(){
    $("#divA").load("book.html #divB");
});
```

or you can also do this way:

```
$("#divlinkholder a:eq(0)").click(function(){
    $("#divA").load("book.html #divB");
});
```

:eq is zero based index property so your first link at index 0 will load the content if you want to load it with 3rd link then change it to :eq(2)